# Is it possible to use message Pact for ActiveSupport::Notification messages?

Tags: pact, activesupport

Message Pact is non Http approach, see for more details:
https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/how_pact_works#non-http-testing-message-pact

ActiveSupport::Notification - is part of [Rails ActiveSupport][1], see for more details:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Notifications

As I understand, ActiveSupport::Notification is using memory for a queue underneath, but not the external requests that are expected by Pact, so probably it can be done only via some other Message Queue, like Kafka, for example:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("my_message") do |payload|
  Kafka.produce(queue: 'test-queue', message: payload)
end
```

where `Kafka.produce` can be handled by Pact.

However, in this way, there is makes sense to remove ActiveSupport::Notifications and keep using only Kafka but this is the next step.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question sorry Alex, could you please reframe it to clarify what your needs are?

Comment: Hi @MatthewFellows thanks for the reply, the idea basically is to start using Pact non Http approach for ActiveSupport::Notifications in rails to later replace ActiveSupport::Notifications to Kafka and keep unchanged contracts.